React-Native yamap route
I can't find a normal route finding method for navigator on React-Native, I'm using the react-native-yamap library.
I tried using openRouteService, but the application refuses to work. It gives an error that the server is not responding.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
